# How to Use an inside foreach use foreach in asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

Can I view a table within a table in Razor
Ex:

```
foreach (var item in Model) 
{   
    foreach (var item2 in Model2) 
    {
        //I want to put here last table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a foreach loop inside a foreach loop. However you can only iterate over a property of your Model that implements IEnumerable interface. Take for instance this sample Model.

```
public class Team
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

And Member.cs be

```
    public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FullNames { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
}
```

In your view, if you want to iterate over a collection of **Team**s and list the members names then you can do this

```
@model IEnumerable<Team>

 <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(a => a.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(a => a.Founded)</th>
        <th>Players</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    @foreach (var team in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => team.Name)</td>

            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => team.Founded)</td>

            <td>
                @foreach (var member in team.Members)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(a => member.FullNames)
                    </div>
                }
            </td>

        </tr>        
    }        
</table>
```

As you can see, am iterating over all Teams displaying the Name and Founded details as well as a full names of members for each Team

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build table you can do it with **table** tag, but I recommend to use Html [WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        <tr>
            <td>
            @foreach (var item2 in item.AnotherCollection)
            {
                ...
            }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I want to put foreach here in <td>

Comment: @سلطان اليامي see example

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I just typed `@` and it came up as the first autocomplete, so I just pressed the Tab key and it inserted it. I'm guessing Andrey did the same thing.

Comment: @doug65536 Ha ha, yeah you're right. And BTW, try typing the second character of my name. ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ just copy-paste)